# Testing Play Framework application within a web browser throws exception once JQuery 2.X is included

Tags: scala, selenium, playframework

I have a super simple integration test (pretty much a [copy and paste from the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaFunctionalTest#WithBrowser)) that is being used to display a very bare bones HTML page.

Without JQuery being included on that HTML page (as a locally hosted script), the test runs perfectly fine. But when I include JQuery, I get a very lengthy error, of which the most useful part seem

```
[error]    WebDriverException: : com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (http://localhost:19001/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js#2)
[error] Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: '14fa800511cc5d66d426e08b0b2ab926c7ed7398', time: '2013-12-16 13:18:38'
[error] System info: host: 'Mike', ip: '172.16.1.63', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
[error] Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver  (HtmlUnitDriver.java:484)
```

**What is this error and how can I test my application** (which requires JQuery, but the execution of JS is not required by the test suite)?

I also tried using the Firefox web driver (from the example in the documentation linked above), but it results in a type mismatch compilation error:

```
[error]  found   : Class[org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver]
[error]  required: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
[error]     "run in a browser" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = FIREFOX) {
[error]                                                       ^
[error] F:\Documents\Projects\EatSafe\test\IntegrationSpec.scala:15: too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
[error]     "run in a browser" in new WithBrowser(webDriver = FIREFOX) {
```

Comment: As an aside, I already tried [the advice mentioned here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2607) with no success (same error).

Comment: I also note that this seems to be a JQuery version thing, as the latest JQuery 1.X works fine.

Comment: For anyone else who has this problem, I simply gave up on using jQuery 2.X and used 1.X (same interface, anyway). I suspect it's because of an incompatible JS engine.